# Want to parse a file and reformat it to create a pairRDD in Spark through Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have dataset in a file in the form:

```
1: 1664968

2: 3 747213 1664968 1691047 4095634 5535664

3: 9 77935 79583 84707 564578 594898 681805 681886 835470 880698 

4: 145

5: 8 57544 58089 60048 65880 284186 313376 

6: 8
```

I need to transform this to something like below using Spark and Scala as a part of preprocessing of data:

```
1 1664968

2 3

2 747213

2 1664968

2 4095634 

2 5535664

3 9

3 77935

3 79583

3 84707
```

And so on....

Can anyone provide input on how this can be done.
The length of the original rows in the file varies as shown in the dataset example above.

I am not sure, how to go about doing this transformation.

I tried soemthing like below which gives me a pair of the key and the first element after the semi-colon.

But I am not sure how to iterate over the entire data and generate the pairs as needed.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Graphx").setMaster("local"))
  val rawLinks = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/links-simple-sorted-top100.txt")

  rawLinks.take(5).foreach(println)

  val formattedLinks = rawLinks.map{ rows =>
    val fields = rows.split(":")
    val fromVertex = fields(0)
    val toVerticesArray = fields(1).split(" ")
    (fromVertex, toVerticesArray(1))
  }

  val topFive = formattedLinks.take(5)
  topFive.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("1: 1664968","2: 3 747213 1664968 1691047 4095634 5535664"))
val keyValues = rdd.flatMap(line => {
  val Array(key, values) = line.split(":",2)
  for(value <- values.trim.split("""\s+""")) 
    yield (key, value.trim)
})
keyValues.collect
```

Answer (score 0):

split row in 2 parts and map on variable number of columns.

```
def transform(s: String): Array[String] = { 
  val Array(head, tail) = s.split(":", 2)
  tail.trim.split("""\s+""").map(x => s"$head $x")
}

> transform("2: 3 747213 1664968 1691047 4095634 5535664")
// Array(2 3, 2 747213, 2 1664968, 2 1691047, 2 4095634, 2 5535664)
```